# Connect to socket-io already defined in index.js using external node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, hapi.js

I am using hapijs in my MEAN stack and implemented socket.io (using this for reference: http://matt-harrison.com/using-hapi-js-with-socket-io/) Everything works fine, no problems there. It works great in my application!

However, there will be script I will be running via command line separately (which will be doing some maintenance on the application) that I was hoping to connect to the same web socket and be able to push to clients messages if data needs to be refreshed.

My index.js taken straight from the example:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

var io = require('socket.io')(server.listener);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.emit('Hello');

});

server.start();
```

I tried to create a separate JS file, and do a:

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(3000);
```

Then passed io to send a message. This doesn't seem right... I guess I'm wondering if this can even be done. Messing around I've either created a separate web socket or no connection to the client.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks.
T

Comment: if you are using socket this worth a try https://github.com/hapijs/nes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your provided code, you're creating 2 servers. `[io.listen()][1]` listens on a port as a server.

What you need to do instead to pass messages around is to create a [socket.io client](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/) in your separate script. There's a separate module for this called socket.io-client, which you can require to be a client:

### client.js

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('beep', function () {
    console.log('beep');
    socket.emit('boop');
});
```

### server.js

Here's a slightly updated version of your server script too (hapi v9.0.0 has a mandatory callback for `server.start()`):

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

var io = require('socket.io')(server.listener);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('beep');
    socket.on('boop', function () {
        console.log('boop');
    });
});

server.start(function () {
    console.log('Started Server!');
});
```

If you open up a couple of terminals and run these, you should see messages passed between them and `beep` and `boop` logged out:

[image]